# Anaconda Python install imutils in Windows10

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using **Anaconda2 Python2.7** with **Windows 10** . How can I install the package **imutils**?

When I type: `conda install imutils`

It returns

```
Error:  Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - imutils
```

And then I search it

```
anaconda search -t conda imutils
```

[image]

It seems that there is only the OSX version, but not the windows version.

Are there any methods that can install imutils in Anaconda Windows 10?

Comment: So far there is no build for windows available on anaconda cloud. Unless you build your own conda recipe, it is not possible to install it with conda. Note that you can install with `pip install imutils`, provided the package supports windows.

Answer (score 9):

Did you try running these commands:

```py
import pip  
pip.main(['install', 'package-name'])
```

Answer (score 8):

You can install `pip` on the anaconda platform.

1. Use

   ```
   conda install pip
   ```
2. Then use `pip` to install `imutils`:

   ```
   pip install imutils
   ```

The package will get installed.

Answer (score 2):

Imutils in anaconda for Windows 10 64-bit:

```
conda install -c pjamesjoyce imutils
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Anaconda3 Python3.6 with Windows 7, but the command seems the same: `pip install imutils`

```
c:\>pip install imutils
Collecting imutils
  Downloading imutils-0.4.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: imutils
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for imutils ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\09\42\86\
d9e60e31cc4bec207af96ac3cda32b2ce6475a8883ec0d6b99
Successfully built imutils
Installing collected packages: imutils
Successfully installed imutils-0.4.0

c:\>anaconda search -t conda imutils
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
Packages:
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
     STScI/imutils             | 0.0.0.git | conda           | osx-64
                                          : imutils
     mlgill/imutils            |    0.3.6 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
     thecampfire/imutils       |    0.3.1 | conda           | osx-64
```

For those who's using Python 2.7, write the same command with path to pip2.7.exe file `c:\Python27\Scripts\pip2.7.exe install imutils`

```
c:\>c:\Python27\Scripts\pip2.7.exe install imutils
Collecting imutils
  Using cached imutils-0.4.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: imutils
  Running setup.py install for imutils ... done
Successfully installed imutils-0.4.0

c:\>c:\Python27\Scripts\pip2.7.exe show imutils
Name: imutils
Version: 0.4.0
Summary: A series of convenience functions to make basic image processing
functions such as translation, rotation, resizing, skeletonization, displaying
Matplotlib images, sorting contours, detecting edges, and much more easier
with OpenCV and both Python 2.7 and Python 3.
Home-page: https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils
Author: Adrian Rosebrock
Author-email: adrian@pyimagesearch.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Requires:
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of these answers are outdated. The imutils package is available at conda-forge. It's generally a bad idea to use both anaconda and pip in the same environment

`conda install -c conda-forge imutils`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58792964/12334204

Answer (score 0):

compatible with python 3.5.x

```
conda install -c mlgill imutils
```

Answer (score 0):

imutls is not supported in anaconda Win64

pip install imutils

`https://anaconda.org/mlgill/imutils`

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in Anaconda prompt

```
pip install imutils
```