# How to install imutils library in anaconda 3.4.4?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I use OpenCV environment in Anaconda Navigator, so I download it from environments icon in the left side on screen in Navigator but I didn't find the **imutils** library in it! So, *how can I get the **imutlis** library*?

I tried this in Anaconda Prompt :

```
conda install pip
pip install imutils
```

and didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The **imutils** library [is available from Conda Forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/imutils), so I recommend installing it from there.

```
conda install -c conda-forge imutils
```

Generally, one should avoid using `pip` in the **base** env because it frequently leads to an unmanageable package state. Please see "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)".

Comment: It's true that pip inside conda is generally a bad idea but for the imutils library, the conda-forge install seems to fail and the pip install works.